# Sound cannot be played in the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, audio

I have set a sound in a "raw" file. However, when I put everything together, the original click sound on emulator is playing but my "mouse click" sound is not.

I have my mouse click sound set to "sound1".

The sound is only 1 second long I do not know if that matters.

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Activity1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Special_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/button_images"
        android:onClick="playSound"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();

        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();


    } else {
        soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                0);
    }

    sound1 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);

    button = findViewById(R.id.Special_Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openActivity2();
        }
    });

}

public void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void playSound(View v) {
    soundPool.play(R.raw.sound1, 1,1,0
    ,0,1);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    soundPool.release();
    soundPool = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have implemented an **onClick** in your XML, as well as **setOnClickListener** in your Java.

So as far as I can tell, your code is running the onClickListener which is starting your openActivity2() method, and skipping the playSound() method.

Try removing the onClick in your XML and integrating playSound() into the **setOnClickListener** instead.

You could also add in AudioFocus request. 
This code works: In my case I have used a fragment class but this can be used in any activity.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;



public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

    //These are the declarations

    Button btn;

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    //This tells the media player what to do if AudioFocus is changed
    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener 
       mOnAudioFocusChangeListener =
        new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

                if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT ||
                        focusChange ==   AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK){

                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN){
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS){
                    releaseMediaPlayer();
                }
            }
        };

//This tells the media player what to do when the playback is done
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.**YOUR LAYOUT HERE**,container,false);

    //This assigns the audio manager to this view 
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /* First calls the releaseMediaPlayer() method to make sure there
             * are no other instances of the media player that exist. 
             */
            releaseMediaPlayer();

            //This requests the AudioFocus
            int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            //This if statement deals with the above request
            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), **YOUR MEDIA RESOURCE HERE**);
                mMediaPlayer.start();

                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}

//This tells the media player to stop if the app is closed
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

//This method is to release the instance of the media player
private void releaseMediaPlayer(){

    if (mMediaPlayer != null){

            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
            mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay, have you tried implementing AudioFocus Request?

I will edit my answer to include working code for playing a media file.

Comment: @Longhorns2102 did you get it fixed?